# Why do you use timestamp on I2C?

Tags: i2c

## Links

1. [PCF85263A Datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCF85263A.pdf)7
2. [I<sup>2</sup>C Monitoring Devices](http://www.telos.info/i2c-product-comparison/i2c-tracer/)

Comment: [We have already seen this before](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189272/what-does-mechanism-is-working-in-timestamps-in-i2c), smart fellow.  We still (for the 3rd time) have no clue about where you are reading these things from.

Comment: I've done this when debugging sometimes but can't imagine why you need it in a final implementation.

Comment: Did you actually read the document you linked to?  Those are for providing a real time clock to devices that need a clock.  Say you have a datalogger that needs to stamp each data row with an accurate time and date.  You could implement a clock in your circuit or microprocessor, or you could use a PCF85263A (from the link) to provide a date and time.  Cheaper, easier, and less trouble than trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really make sense. Can you give us an example where you saw that?

It's quite common that an RTC (Real Time Clock) is connected via I2C but I2C itself doesn't have a concept of timekeeping.

You *could* (I haven't seen this in reality in the past) deduct a time from the clock frequency or from various packets but as said before, this is just a theoretical concept which doesn't have any useful implications. There are better ways for this.

Comment: That's an RTC, its purpose is timekeeping. This is not really related to I2C except for that the protocol you use to communication with the IC is I2C. The second link is a protocol debugger. Its purpose is to help you debugging, therefore it keeps timestamps when a specific I2C packet was sent/received BUT does not rely on I2C for timestamping